# Postfix configuration in Ubuntu is not sendin e-mail to Yahoo

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, sendmail

Is the first time that I configure a Postfix Mail service in Ubuntu. The situation I'm facing is that recover password e-mails are being sent to G-mail accounts, but no e-mails are being sent to Yahoo e-mails accounts.  I configured Postfix for Google Apps which is what I'm using to manage e-mails for my domain.  From the mail error log I got:

```
Nov 22 22:46:41 ip-172-31-xx-xx postfix/smtp[25837]: 6AEE443548: to=<nxxxxxz@yahoo.com>, relay=alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.xxx.xx]:25, delay=1.3, delays=0.01/0/0.92/0.37, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.xxx.xx] said: 550-5.1.1   Learn more at 550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 g9si5019491qhg.69 - gsmtp (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Nov 22 22:46:42 ip-172-31-xx-xx postfix/cleanup[25835]: 13C7443549: message-id=<20151122224642.13C7443549@ip-172-31-xx-xx.ec2.internal>
Nov 22 22:46:42 ip-172-31-xx-xx postfix/qmgr[1196]: 13C7443549: from=<>, size=3433, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 22 22:46:42 ip-172-31-xx-xx postfix/bounce[25838]: 6AEE443548: sender non-delivery notification: 13C7443549
Nov 22 22:46:42 ip-172-31-xx-xx postfix/qmgr[1196]: 6AEE443548: removed
```

My instance is an AWS Ec2 Instance using Ubuntu, and Apache.

If you need to gave a look to another .cf mail configuration file please let me know so that I can provide it to you.

I'm assuming is a special Yahoo servers configuration that is not permitting to receive e-mails.  I've search to see if my domain is blacklisted, but everything appears to be ok in the records that I've read.

How an I solve this problem?  Do I have to add an special configuration to my  Postfix so I can send e-mails to Yahoo?

Regards,

Nelitza M.

Than you very much for your time.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Why are you trying to relay Yahoo mail through Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more going on but with this message it appears that the address in invalid.

550, "5.1.1", The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or unnecessary spaces. For more inform

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596

Comment: Is my own e-mail address the one I'm using to test, and is well written.

Comment: I don't have enough info to tell you more... Just telling you what your error is saying. :)

Comment: I know, thank you.  Others users from Yahoo are experimenting the same thing...Maybe its a google app configuration.  I'll keep everyone posted about the issue.  If anyone else has something else in mind, please share it I will implement your solution and provide feedback if it solved it or not.

Comment: Are you able to relay to other domains besides google.com?

Comment: Is not sending to Outlook either.  I assume its only sending to Google Apps related accounts and to Gmail accounts. How do I add others e-mails provider to the Postfix configurations or how do I enable to send it to other emails provider different from Google Apps or G-mail accounts?

Comment: I found this that seems similar. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91209/do-we-need-to-configure-postfix-for-using-google-apps-gmail

Comment: I came to the conclusion that the problem was related to the Google App third party configuration in my Postfix. What I proceeded to do is to remove it, install it again using the standard Ubuntu configuration.  Now its working for all the email providers.

Thank you for the feedback Eddie Dunn.

Answer (score 0):

How I resolved my problem is to re-install Postfix using the following configuration:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Now its working for every e-mal provider.